# How to make an elasticsearch query that filters on the maximum value of a field?

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to be able to query for text but also retrieve only the results with the maximum value of a certain integer field in my data.  I have read the docs about aggregations and filters and I don't quite see what I am looking for.

For instance, I have some repeating data that gets indexed that is the same except for an integer field - let's call this field `lastseen`.

So, as an example, given this data put into elasticsearch:

```
  //  these two the same except "lastseen" field
  curl -XPOST localhost:9200/myindex/myobject -d '{
    "field1": "dinner carrot potato broccoli",
    "field2": "something here",
    "lastseen": 1000
  }'

  curl -XPOST localhost:9200/myindex/myobject -d '{
    "field1": "dinner carrot potato broccoli",
    "field2": "something here",
    "somevalue": 100
  }'

  # and these two the same except "lastseen" field
  curl -XPOST localhost:9200/myindex/myobject -d '{
    "field1": "fish chicken something",
    "field2": "dinner",
    "lastseen": 2000
  }'

  curl -XPOST localhost:9200/myindex/myobject -d '{
    "field1": "fish chicken something",
    "field2": "dinner",
    "lastseen": 200
  }'
```

If I query for `"dinner"`

```
  curl -XPOST localhost:9200/myindex -d '{  
   "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "dinner"
        }
    }
    }'
```

I'll get 4 results back.   I'd like to have a filter such that I only get two results back - only the items with the maximum `lastseen` field.

This is ***obviously not right***, but hopefully it gives you an idea of what I am after:

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "dinner"
        }
    },
    "filter": {
          "max": "lastseen"
        }

}
```

The results would look something like:

```
"hits": [
      {
        ...
        "_source": {
          "field1": "dinner carrot potato broccoli",
          "field2": "something here",
          "lastseen": 1000
        }
      },
      {
        ...
        "_source": {
          "field1": "fish chicken something",
          "field2": "dinner",
          "lastseen": 2000
        }
      } 
   ]
```

**update 1:**   I tried creating a mapping that excluded `lastseen` from being indexed.   This did not work.  Still getting all 4 results back.

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/myindex -d '{  
    "mappings": {
      "myobject": {
        "properties": {
          "lastseen": {
            "type": "long",
            "store": "yes",
            "include_in_all": false
          }
        }
      }
    }
}'
```

**update 2:**
I tried a deduplication with the agg scheme [listed here,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25448186/remove-duplicate-documents-from-a-search-in-elasticsearch) and it did not work, but more importantly, I don't see a way to combine that with a keyword search.

Comment: What if you had two docs with `lastseen: 2000`, you want both returned or one with `lastseen: 2000` and one with `lastseen: 1000`?

Comment: Also, what do you consider as a duplicate document? I see that  you recognize this type of docs as the ones having the same `field1`.

Comment: @AndreiStefan a duplicate document would have the same field1 and field2.

Comment: Then you can use the approach I described in your other post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31553928/elasticsearch-copy-to-field-not-behaving-as-expected-with-aggregations. Use `_source` transformation to concatenate both fields to a `not_analyzed` third field and use that in the aggregation I specified in my answer: `"terms": {
        "field": "all_fields",
        "size": 2
      }`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not ideal, but I think it gets you what you need.

Change the mapping of your `field1` field, assuming this is the one that you use to define "duplicate" documents, like this:

```
PUT /lastseen
{
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "properties": {
        "field1": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "raw": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        },
        "field2": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "lastseen": {
          "type": "long"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

meaning, you add a `.raw` subfield that is `not_analyzed` which means it will be indexed just the way it is, no analysis and split into terms. This is to make possible the somewhat "duplicate documents spotting".

Then, you need to use a `terms` aggregation on `field1.raw` (for duplicates) and a `top_hits` sub-aggregation to get a single document for each `field1` value:

```
GET /lastseen/test/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "dinner"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "field1_unique": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "field1.raw",
        "size": 2
      },
      "aggs": {
        "first_one": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "sort": [{"lastseen": {"order":"desc"}}]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Also, that single document returned by `top_hits` is the one with the highest `lastseen` (thing made possible by `"sort": [{"lastseen": {"order":"desc"}}]`).

The results you will get back are these (under `aggregations` not `hits`):

```
   ...
   "aggregations": {
      "field1_unique": {
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
         "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "dinner carrot potato broccoli",
               "doc_count": 2,
               "first_one": {
                  "hits": {
                     "total": 2,
                     "max_score": null,
                     "hits": [
                        {
                           "_index": "lastseen",
                           "_type": "test",
                           "_id": "AU60ZObtjKWeJgeyudI-",
                           "_score": null,
                           "_source": {
                              "field1": "dinner carrot potato broccoli",
                              "field2": "something here",
                              "lastseen": 1000
                           },
                           "sort": [
                              1000
                           ]
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "key": "fish chicken something",
               "doc_count": 2,
               "first_one": {
                  "hits": {
                     "total": 2,
                     "max_score": null,
                     "hits": [
                        {
                           "_index": "lastseen",
                           "_type": "test",
                           "_id": "AU60ZObtjKWeJgeyudJA",
                           "_score": null,
                           "_source": {
                              "field1": "fish chicken something",
                              "field2": "dinner",
                              "lastseen": 2000
                           },
                           "sort": [
                              2000
                           ]
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
```

Comment: Thank you.  This is exactly what I was looking for.