# elasticsearch copy_to field not behaving as expected with aggregations

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index mapping with two string fields, `field1` and `field2`, both being declared as copy_to to another field called `all_fields`.  `all_fields` is indexed as "not_analyzed".

When I create a bucket aggregation on `all_fields`, I was expecting distinct buckets with keys of field1 and field2 concatenated together.  Instead, I get separate buckets with keys of field1 and field2 unconcatenated.

Example:
mapping:

```
  {
    "mappings": {
      "myobject": {
        "properties": {
          "field1": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "analyzed",
            "copy_to": "all_fields"
          },
          "field2": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "analyzed",
            "copy_to": "all_fields"
          },
          "all_fields": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

data in:

```
  {
    "field1": "dinner carrot potato broccoli",
    "field2": "something here",
  }
```

and

```
  {
    "field1": "fish chicken something",
    "field2": "dinner",
  }
```

aggregation:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "t": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "all_fields"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

results:

```
...
"aggregations": {
    "t": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
            {
                "key": "dinner",
                "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
                "key": "dinner carrot potato broccoli",
                "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
                "key": "fish chicken something",
                "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
                "key": "something here",
                "doc_count": 1
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I was expecting only 2 buckets, `fish chicken somethingdinner` and `dinner carrot potato broccolisomethinghere`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is concatenation of two strings. `copy_to` even if it seems is doing this, it is not. With `copy_to` you are, conceptually, creating a set of values from both `field1` and `field2`, not concatenating them.

For your use case, you have two options:

1. use [`_source` transformation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/mapping-transform.html#mapping-transform)
2. perform a script aggregation

I would recommend `_source` transformation as I think it's more efficient than doing the scripting. Meaning, you pay a little price at indexing time than doing a heavy scripting aggregation.

For **`_source` transformation**:

```
PUT /lastseen
{
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "transform": {
        "script": "ctx._source['all_fields'] = ctx._source['field1'] + ' ' + ctx._source['field2']"
      }, 
      "properties": {
        "field1": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "field2": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "lastseen": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "all_fields": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the query:

```
GET /lastseen/test/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "NAME": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "all_fields",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For **script aggregation**, to be easier to do (meaning, using `doc['field'].value` rather than the more expensive `_source.field`) add `.raw` sub-fields to `field1` and `field2`:

```
PUT /lastseen
{
  "mappings": {
    "test": { 
      "properties": {
        "field1": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "raw": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        },
        "field2": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "raw": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        },
        "lastseen": {
          "type": "long"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the script will use these `.raw` subfields:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "NAME": {
      "terms": {
        "script": "doc['field1.raw'].value + ' ' + doc['field2.raw'].value", 
        "size": 10,
        "lang": "groovy"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Without the `.raw` sub-fields (which are made on purpose as `not_analyzed`) you would have needed to do something like this, which is more expensive:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "NAME": {
      "terms": {
        "script": "_source.field1 + ' ' + _source.field2", 
        "size": 10,
        "lang": "groovy"
      }
    }
  }
}
```