# Exclude similar documents (duplicates) from result

Tags: elasticsearch, levenshtein-distance

I store all articles from some news sources. A news article that originates from e.g. Cnn.com, might be reposted by others. In effect I end up saving the same articles many times.

If I do a search for 'Tesla' I might get 3 articles that are 90% equal to each other. I can compare and filter duplicates in my app using the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance), but I rather have ES filtering it.

Is there a way I can say `give me all articles matching WORD, but only return the first if other hits are more than 90% equal to the first`?

Cheers,
Martin

Answer (score 1):

If you really *need* to keep all this records in ES (instead of filtering out with levenshtein *before* indexing), than you're probably looking for [top hits aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) with field collapsing.

Also take a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25448186/remove-duplicate-documents-from-a-search-in-elasticsearch)