# Elasticsearch: Remove duplicates from search results of analyzed fields

Tags: elasticsearch, duplicates

I have entries in my index like follows:

```
 ID   BuildingName  Postalcode Type
  1   ABCD             1234     1
  2   ABCD             7890     1
```

I need to remove duplicates appearing in the 'BuildingName' field *at search*  (not at index since you see they are two different entries) . Finally I only want to see (any of the buildings with the searched name)

```
ID   BuildingName  Postalcode Type
  1   ABCD             1234     1
```

why I cannot use field collapsing/aggregation as described here ([Remove duplicate documents from a search in Elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25448186/remove-duplicate-documents-from-a-search-in-elasticsearch)) -> because i need BuildingName to be n-gram analyzed and the field collapsing / aggregation works only on non analyzed fields.

Any way to accomplishing this?
All help appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a sub-field to `BuildingName` field which should be `not_analyzed` or analyzed with an analyzer like `keyword` which shouldn't change the text much. While you search on the normal `BuildingName` field that is nGram-ed, the aggregation is performed on the sub-field which is not changed:

- the mapping:

```
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "properties": {
        "BuildingName": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "my_ngram_analyzer",
          "fields": {
            "notAnalyzed": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

- the query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "BuildingName": {
        "value": "ab"
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "unique": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "BuildingName.notAnalyzed",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sample": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. Doing what you suggested had no effect on the fields returned....I am wondering I am also suppossed to duplicate the BuildingName in the "notAnalyzed" subfield? since I assume no data is actually being stored now in that subfield...

Comment: What do you mean? I don't understand. Can you update the original post with what you tried, what you got back and why that's a problem?

Comment: I added the subfiled to the BuildingName field and specified it as 'not analyzed' in the mapping. Then I posted the same query as you have written. The search results come back same as before I did all this- i.e. with duplicate BuildingName .

Comment: Please, post the updated mapping and the result you get back.