# Dedup elasticsearch results using multiple fields as unique key

Tags: elasticsearch, duplicates

There have been similar question asked to this (see [Remove duplicate documents from a search in Elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25448186/remove-duplicate-documents-from-a-search-in-elasticsearch)) but I haven't found a way to dedup using multiple fields as the "unique key". Here's a simple example to illustrate a bit of what I'm looking for:

Say this is our raw data:

```
{ "name": "X", "event": "A", "time": 1 }
{ "name": "X", "event": "B", "time": 2 }
{ "name": "X", "event": "B", "time": 3 }
{ "name": "Y", "event": "A", "time": 4 }
{ "name": "Y", "event": "C", "time": 5 }
```

I would essentially like to get the distinct event counts based on name and event. I want to avoid double counting the event B which happened on the same name X twice, so the counts I'd be looking for are:

```
event: A, count: 2
event: B, count: 1
event: C, count: 1
```

Is there a way to set up an agg query as seen in the related question? Another option I've deliberated is to index the object with a special key field (i.e. "X_A", "X_B", etc.). I could then simply dedup on this field. I'm not sure which is a preferred approach, but I'd personally prefer not to index the data with extra metadata.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify a script in a `terms` aggregation in order to build a key out of multiple fields:

```
POST /test/dedup/_search
{
  "aggs":{
    "dedup" : {
      "terms":{
        "script": "[doc.name.value, doc.event.value].join('_')"
       },
       "aggs":{
         "dedup_docs":{
           "top_hits":{
             "size":1
           }
         }
       }    
    }
  }
}
```

This will basically provide the following results:

- X_A: 1
- X_B: 2
- Y_A: 1
- Y_C: 1

Note: There's only one event `C` in your sample data, so the count cannot be two unless I'm missing something.

Comment: You're right about the C count, just a typo by me. Fixed it