# Eliminate duplicates in elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the problem that some documents are indexed twice or more so I want to filter out this duplicates when searching. I followed some other threads and built this query:

```
{
  "query" : { ... },
  "size" : 10,
  "from" : 0,
  "sort" : { ... },
  "aggs" : {
    "dedup" : {
      "terms" : {
        "field" : "content.keyword"
      },
      "aggs" : {
        "dedup_docs" : {
          "top_hits" : {
            "size" : 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But it seems that this aggregation has no effect. I'm still getting duplicate results (documents with the same text in the content field).

Request changed:

```
{
  "query" : { ... },
  "size" : 10,
  "from" : 0,
  "sort" : { ... },
  "collapse" : {
    "field" : "content.keyword"
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to filter out duplicate **aggregations** or duplicate document results?

Comment: I want to filter out duplicate document results, let's say documents with the same title or the same text content.

Comment: Are you using the answer from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25448186/remove-duplicate-documents-from-a-search-in-elasticsearch ?

Did you run on the right endpoint? /_search?search_type=count
Did you look for the results in the aggregations and **not** in the _hits_ array?

Answer (score 4):

You can also take a look at the recently added [field collapsing feature](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/search-request-collapse.html)

Comment: Collapsing fields seems to be a good idea and I changed my query (please have a look on my post). But if I execute it, I will get the error: "Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [collapse]."

Comment: field collapsing is only supported in ES 5.4 and later... you might need to upgrade

Comment: I updated my elastic instance and it works perfect. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Field collapsing works good but is it possible to get the number of total hits (count without duplicates)?

Comment: No, as mentioned on the docs page: The total number of hits in the response indicates the number of matching documents without collapsing. The total number of distinct group is unknown.